# Progress Bar in HTML by PHP

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have found a progress bar  in a tutorial, and wanted to use at my website.

What I want to do:

- If row $pHour is between 0-100, I want to show Objective: 100
- If row $pHour is between 101-499 I want to show: Objective: 500
- If row $pHour is between 500-1000, I want to show: Objective: 1000

but, when I try to set max  value higher tha 100, it does not set. Why? the php if's I can create alone, but I don't know why it doesn't show values great than 100

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-updates">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-lg-8">
          <h4 class="panel-title text-success">Hours Active</h4>
          <h3><?php echo $pHour ?></h3>
          <div class="progress">
            <div style="width: <?php echo $pHour ?>%" aria-valuemax="500" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $pHour ?>" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">100% Complete (success)</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>Obiectiv: 500</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-4 text-right">
          <input type="text" value="100" class="dial-success">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- panel -->
</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmszea30/

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to PHP.

Comment: It is. Just removed it, I had the full script which included the PHP part but I removed it, and forgot about php tag.